# Why does my vim-powerline not express unicodes?

Tags: vim, plugins

I returned to vim after know about 'Vundle' installer, so that I installed vim-powerline through Vundle, and I checked its result, but it is not work.

I set my locale setting from `ko_KR.UTF-8` to `en_US.UTF-8` by editing `.bashrc`. However, the result is under the picture.

[image]

I don't know why this result.

Comment: Are you sure its powerline? Does your terminal emulator support utf-8?

Comment: @FDinoff I checked my terminal(xterm) does not support utf-8, at first I typed a unicode character, echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac' but it does not still express euro, so it is my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @FDinoff But, I don't know still why my terminal does not support UTF-8. Before reinstalled my computer, It was ubuntu 12.04 32bit machine, vim-powerline has not problem but I reinstalled my os 64bit version, problem came out.

Comment: What os are currently using? (Still ubuntu?). Also you might want to try different characters. Your current font might not support the euro character

Comment: @FDinoff Yep, I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit version.